# Distance to uniform distribution for continuous probability distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, distance, metric

I need to quantify the distance of a continuous probability distribution $f(x)$ to the uniform distribution on $x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$. Do you know any distance functions that could help here? For example, f-divergence does not help... I need the distance to be a finite number and at the same time capable to separate between different non-uniform distributions, e.g., I would like to see a normal distribution with width $\sigma^2 = 2$ closer to a uniform distribution than a normal distribution with width $\sigma^2 = 1$.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the Wasserstein metric? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric

Comment: But note that the uniform distribution on $(-\infty, +\infty)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: As @fblundun notes, there is no uniform distribution with a support on the entire real line. Are you looking for a reasonable distance from a flat zero line? For something like a normal distribution, you could look at the maximum of the density (then larger $\sigma^2$ would yield smaller "distances from zero", as you require), but that would not work for distributions with unbounded densities, like the gamma with $k<1$. Or you could simply use the reciprocal of the variance. Can you add some detail as to what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your help. At least the Wasserstein $l_1$ metric has the same problem and diverges to $+\infty$ I guess. More precisely, I have multivariate $t$-distributions. Measuring the height of the maximum could actually work here! Thanks:)

Comment: If you're looking for "which of these is flatter," why not use the differential entropy?

Comment: thanks! Also a good idea:)

Comment: Are you confusing the uniform distribution with the Jeffrey's prior?